# IBM Cloud App ID: Forget Password and re-authentication flow

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I’m new to IBM Cloud App ID application development.

I want to implement a password change function for users to forget their passwords and re-authentication function after renew their password.
What kind of application flow do I need to implement this function and what timing is the access token issued?

I’m referring to the following document but I'm not sure.
https://github.com/ibm-cloud-security/appid-clientsdk-swift/blob/17be22659b95d8e78f4bbdda4e571e20b16f4f31/README.md

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Are you aware of the API docs like this one for "forgot password"? https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/app-id/management#starts-the-forgot-password-process

Answer (score 0):

App ID offers two options for implementing a forgot password flow.

1. The default App ID experience and UI: 
   App ID provides a default UI for your users to request to reset their password. Your users can access it by clicking on the "forgot password" link in the sign in UI. Or you can programmatically bring up the forgot password screen using this:

   ```
    AppID.sharedInstance.loginWidget?.launchForgotPassword(delegate: delegate())
   ```
2. You can completely customize the flow in any way you want to using the [REST API](https://appid-management.ng.bluemix.net/swagger-ui/#/Cloud_Directory_operations). This way you can provide your own branding and control every aspect of the flow. However you will need to do the "plumbing" yourself, and call those APIs from a server side component that your iOS app can talk to.